# How to add specific phrase to end of search url

Tags: permalinks, search

I need to add the following string :

```
=&a=true
```

To the end of all search URLs,  but only those generated by the form below.    So instead of this URL :

```
https://website.com/?s=tool&post_type=ait-item
```

It would display this URL :

```
https://website.com/?s=tool&post_type=ait-item=&a=true
```

I suspect I could do it by editing the custom search form,  but am unsure how to accomplish this.  This is the search form :

```
<div class="search-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <form method="get" class="nt-search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <input type="text" id="search-text" class="input-text" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Search &#8230;', 'customsearch');?>" autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="ait-item" />
                <i class="fa fa-times close-button" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways But the easiest will be the following code.

The key is the `GET` method that will allow us to inject what you want.

You can try:

```
<div class="search-box">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <form method="get" class="nt-search-form" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <input type="text" id="search-text" class="input-text" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Search &#8230;', 'customsearch');?>" autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="ait-item" />
                <input type="hidden" name="a" value="true" />
                <i class="fa fa-times close-button" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Update

I marked out the `=&a=true` the first equal as this will be set the GET variable `post_type` to include the equal symbol.

If this actually what you want you to have to replace with this line `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="ait-item=" />`